# extracting rows out of a table based on a string

Tags: r

I'm using a dataset that has a lot of rows but I only want to keep rows based on their value in col A. Here is a snippet of my table;

```
ï..hlpi_name        year    age size    income  expenditure eqv_income  eqv_exp
All households      2008    35.9    2.7 46704   42394       26869       25132
Beneficiary         2008    29.9    2.6 23404   25270       14258       15824
Income quintile 1   2008    40.0    2.3 16747   21145       13402       14408
random figure       2008    34.7    2.8 31308   29855       18917       18266
Income quintile 3   2008    31.5    3.0 49106   46561       26870       24672
Income quintile 4   2008    35.3    2.6 61674   52776       36691       31958
```

So using *tidyverse* i've tried the following code;

```
gfDS2 <- gfDS
gfDS2 <- gfDS2 %>%
filter(!grepl("All households", ï..hlpi_name))
filter(!grepl("Beneficiary", ï..hlpi_name))
filter(!grepl("expenditure quintile 1", ï..hlpi_name))
filter(!grepl("expenditure quintile 2", ï..hlpi_name))
filter(!grepl("expenditure quintile 3", ï..hlpi_name))
filter(!grepl("expenditure quintile 4", ï..hlpi_name))
filter(!grepl("expenditure quintile 5", ï..hlpi_name))
```

but its giving me this error;

```
Error in grepl("Beneficiary", ï..hlpi_name): object 'ï..hlpi_name' not found
Traceback:

1. filter(!grepl("Beneficiary", ï..hlpi_name))
2. grepl("Beneficiary", ï..hlpi_name)
```

I dont understand why it can't see the column name as an object :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the second line of code , the `%>%` was not present.  In addition, it may be better to backquote if the names begin with special characters

```
library(dplyr)
gfDS2 %>%
   filter(!grepl("All households", `ï..hlpi_name`)) %>%
   filter(!grepl("Beneficiary", `ï..hlpi_name`)) %>%
    ...
```

Comment: i tried the above answer but a new error was thrown from it. any idea?                                             Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:11:0: unexpected end of input
9: filter(!grepl("expenditure quintile 4", `ï..hlpi_name`)) %>%
10: filter(!grepl("expenditure quintile 5 (high)", `ï..hlpi_name`)) %>%
   ^
Traceback:

Comment: @Nad The `...` at the end is to add your other expressions

Comment: yeah, i had done that but had an extra %>% at the end, my bad ^^ thanks for help

Comment: @Nad The reason I didn't add the full code is to make you rewrite the code so that you will understand it better when there is an error

Answer (score 1):

You could also decide to collapse all of them ie:

```
library(dplyr)
gfDS2 %>%
   filter(!grepl("All households|Beneficiary|expenditure quantile [1-5]{1}", `ï..hlpi_name`))
```